# Estimate Shipping is only showing one country (United States)

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, estimate

For some reason my estimate shipping is only listing the United States.

## My Settings

*Enabled shipping methods:*

- UPS
- USPS

  - All countries are allowed for these two shipping methods.

System > Configuration > General > Country options

- Default Country

  - None Selected
- Allowed Countries

  - All Selected

I'm not sure what else to check

Answer (score 3):

The countries that show up are populated from System->Configuration->General->Countries.  Its not related to the countries specified in the carrier configuration, that will only restrict when the quote request is made.